# adding X amount of addChild per maxvalue in loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

The assignment is the spawn several light and dark feathers according to score points from a quiz. The light feathers symbolize the correct points (`light_feather`), and the dark feather are the incorrect points (`dark_feather`) (Each are being tracked). All the feathers are supposed to line up on one line, meaning first light feathers, followed by the dark feathers. I got the quiz dynamics figured out, and the function I have posted here is only for when they press end quiz.

```
var light_feather:LightFeather = new LightFeather();
var dark_feather:DarkFeather = new DarkFeather();

var good_answers:uint = 0;
var bad_answers:uint = 0;

function avsluttFunc (evt:MouseEvent) 
{   
    var sum_LightFeatherX:Number = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < good_answers; i++) {
        addChild(light_feather);
        light_feather.x += 12 + (i*16);
        light_feather.y = 0;
        trace("Lys X-verdi: " + light_feather.x);
        sum_LightFeatherX += Number(light_feather.x);
        return sum_LightFeatherX;
    }
    trace(sum_LightFeatherX);

    dark_feather.x += sum_LightFeatherX;
    for (var j = 1; j <= bad_answers; j++) {
        addChild(dark_feather);
        dark_feather.x += 12 + (j*16);
        dark_feather.y = 0;
        trace("Mørk X-verdi: " + dark_feather.x);
    }

    /*
        //Resetter poengsummen
        good_answers = 0;
        bad_answers = 0;
    */
}
```

Comment: I tried to simplify your code using more readable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you are looking for using only one for loop, take a look :

```
var good_answers:uint = 2;
var bad_answers:uint = 4;

function avsluttFunc(evt:MouseEvent) 
{           
    for (var i:int = 0; i < good_answers + bad_answers; i++) {
        var feather:DisplayObject = i < good_answers ? new LightFeather() : new DarkFeather();  
            feather.x += 12 + i * (feather.width + 1);
            feather.y = 0;
        addChild(feather);          
    }
}
```

This code example will create 4 `DarkFeather` instances next to 2 `LightFeather` ones.

**Edit :**

How to add your objects to an array ?

```
// feathers array should be accessible for both codes (adding and removing objects)
var feathers:Array = [];

for (var i:int = 0; i < good_answers + bad_answers; i++) {
    var feather:DisplayObject = i < good_answers ? new LightFeather() : new DarkFeather();  
    addChild(feather);
    feathers.push(feather);
}
```

then to remove them from the stage, you can do for example :

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < feathers.length; i++) {
    var feather:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(feathers[i]);
        feather.parent.removeChild(feather);
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Quick question: I find when I do the quiz multiple times the feathers lingers from the last quiz. Do you have any method of removing them when I a button to start the quiz again?

Comment: @ripsrpas You can add all your objects to an array, then you can use a for loop on it to remove them later.

Comment: @akamozo:I've tinkered abit with it, but I can only remove the objects from the Array it self. I can't seem to find a way to remove them from the stage. How would you set it up?

Comment: @akamozo Brilliant, just brilliant! Thank you :) Works like a charm